# Dynamic matrix realization with functions in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, memory

guys, i want to realize dynamic 2-dimensions array by using function (for easier creation of arrays, when i will solve different tasks).
I use the next way of memory allocation:

1. Create a large MxN array.
2. Create a array with M elements of pointers.

Code:

```
int  main()
{   
int *A1;
int **A;

A1 = new T  [M*N];
A  = new T* [M];

for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
    A[i]=(A1+(i*M));
    }

delete []A;
delete []A1;    

}
```

But when i want move realization of creating and deleting into h file (because i use templates for ability to create arrays of different types), i have a problem: how to know address of A1 array (MxN array that contains all values of matrix), for preventing a memory leak.
If i'm not mistaken function() in C++ can return only 1 value (**A pointer, but *A1 pointer is will be forget, so in future i can`t delete memory of array A1).

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H


namespace matrix
{


template <typename T> T** create_matrix(int N, int M)
   {

   int *A1;
   int **A;

   A1 = new T  [M*N];
   A  = new T* [M];

   for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
       {
       A[i]=(A1+(i*M));
       }

   return A; //how to return also A1 for preventing memory leack
   }

template <typename T> void delete_matrix(T* A1, T** A)
   {
   delete []A;
   delete []A1;
   }

}


#endif
```

Comment: What about creating a template class to maintain `A1` and `A`?

Comment: functions can return only one value, thats correct, but it also means that they can return basically anything, for example a `struct Foo { int * A1; int ** A; }`

Comment: I didn`t learn about OOP in C++ yet, it will be my future theme for learning, if it possible, explain how to fix this, without OOP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Open the chapter in your C++ book that talks about `std::vector`, and start reading. You'll be amazed to learn that the C++ library can do all these allocations for you, and automatically delete the underlying pointers without you having to worry about a thing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, but std::vector or OOP, or struct only the probably ways for solving this?

Comment: @WhiteBear -- It isn't that `std::vector` is the only way, but if you have work to do, you use `std::vector` to get your work done instead of fiddling around with pointers and dynamic memory.

Comment: I found another way, if You want, You can review, answer 2 please.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a level of encapsulation - create a matrix class and have t manage both memory and pointers. As a positive side effect you will be able to define custom operators for the new data type and improve the readability of the code.

Comment: So only OOP way will be best? Now i don`t know OOP in C++.

Comment: @WhiteBear this is not about OOP. you can define custom data types in C++ just as you can do it in C. C++ added some nice OOP concepts that would be useful for you, but you dont **need** to use them

Comment: Just logical data grouping (best with RAII memory management) and a dedicated type signature so algorithms and operators can recognize it (or be written specifically for it). Not OOP as such.

Comment: Can You have a link when it possible read about this (for beginners)?

Comment: @WhiteBear -- C++ is better learned by reading books and using peer-reviewed tutorials (not any junk you may find on the web).  There is no *one link* someone can give you if you're a beginner, as there is a **lot** to learn as a prerequisite.

Comment: Ok. thanks a lot,lets summarize the main ways for resolving this: std:: vector,  OOP-realization (with memory management), defining own data types, thanks a lot to all.

Comment: @WhiteBear: OOP has nothing to do with your question, with matrices, with RAII or with `std::vector`. OOP is when you use virtual functions to choose an implementation of a common interface at runtime.

Comment: I found another way, if You want, You can review, answer 2 please.

Answer (score 0):

i found another way, because A[0] collects the same memory address like A1, theoretically, when we using `delete []A[0]` this is the similar that `delete []A1`, or no?

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H


namespace matrix
{


template <typename T> T** create_matrix(int N, int M)
   {
   int *A1;
   int **A;

   A1 = new T  [M*N];
   A  = new T* [M];

   for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
      {
      A[i]=(A1+(i*M));
      }

   return A; 
   }

template <typename T> void delete_matrix(T** A)
   {
   delete []A;
   delete []A[0]; //this is must be equivalent to delete []A1
   }



}
#endif
```